# How to cache records in an RxJava stream and consume later in same stream?

Tags: rx-java2

I am investigating the use of RxJava in my current Android Application

I have the following use case and cannot see how to implement it within RxJava.

```
1). Read a set of database records as a Single<List<DBRecord>>
2). Transform each database record to an associated network model class
3). Call a remote Update API for each network object
4). When the remote Update API call is successful, update the specific database record.
```

The code I have so far is

```
    login().andThen(DatabaseController.fetchDBRecord())
        .toObservable()
        .flatMapIterable(dbRecord -> dbRecord)
        .flatMapSingle(database -> transformDatabase(database, DB_RECORD_MAPPER))
        .flatMapSingle(NetworkController::UpdateCall)
        .flatMapCompletable(response -> DatabaseController.updateDBRecord(response.body()))
```

The issue I have is the Update API response is a String value that contains "SUCCESS" or "FAILURE", e.g. the response doesn't identify the current DBRecord details.

Is there any way I can get access to the dbRecord from the `.flatMapIterable(dbRecord -> dbRecord)` stage when I am executing `.flatMapCompletable(response -> DatabaseController.updateDBRecord(response.body()))`

So that I can pass dbRecord into `DatabaseController.updateDBRecord(dbRecord)` like so...

```
login().andThen(DatabaseController.fetchDBRecord())
            .toObservable()
            .flatMapIterable(dbRecord -> dbRecord)
            .flatMapSingle(database -> transformDatabase(database, DB_RECORD_MAPPER))
            .flatMapSingle(NetworkController::UpdateCall)
            .flatMapCompletable(response -> DatabaseController.updateDBRecord(dbRecord))
```

**UPDATED**

I have realised my use case is more complex than originally stated:

```
1). Read a set of database records as a Single<List<DBRecord>>
2). Transform each database record to an associated network model class
3). Call a remote Update API for each network object
4). Only when the remote Update API call is successful, update the specific database record.
```

if I am using nested streams how do I know the nested API call returned successful in my following outer stream to update the database?

```
login().andThen(DatabaseController.fetchDBRecord())
    .flattenAsObservable(dbRecord -> dbRecord)
    .flatMapCompletable(database -> transformDatabase(database, DB_RECORD_MAPPER)
            .flatMap(NetworkController::UpdateCall)
            .flatMapCompletable(response -> DatabaseController.updateDBRecord(database)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested stream. For example:

```
login().andThen(DatabaseController.fetchDBRecord())
    .flattenAsObservable(dbRecord -> dbRecord)
    .flatMapCompletable(database -> transformDatabase(database, DB_RECORD_MAPPER)
            .flatMap(NetworkController::UpdateCall)
            .flatMapCompletable(response -> {
                if (isSuccess(response))
                    return DatabaseController.updateDBRecord(database);
                else
                    return Completable.complete()
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I believe nesting is a good method however I have realised my use case is more complex than I first explained. I've updated my question

Comment: @Hector If I understood correctly, your outer stream does not need to know whether inner `UpdateCall` was successful, because `updateDBRecord` is called in the inner stream. Please check the updated answer to see if that fits the requirements.